# form onsubmit redirect causing the form not being submitted

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have this issue, which I can't seem to solve..

I've got a form which submits the data to a google sheet.

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/sheeturl" method="post" target="hidden_iframe1">
```

which works perfectly fine (but redirects the user to google forms thank you page).

I tried to prevent this behaviour (I want to load a thank you page on my own domain) and added the following onsubmit event

```
onsubmit="window.location.href = 'http://thankyoupage.html';"
```

which by itself doesn't change anything. So I added

```
return false;
```

Now the redirect works fine (loading my thank you page), however the form data is not being submitted to the sheet.

I am pretty sure there's a banal and easy solution for this, but I am just lacking the knowledge to solve it.
Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion would be to let the page submit and finish without a relocation, or relocate at the very end of the script

Comment: You could submit to your own thankyou-page, and use PHP and Google API to achieve the same thing. This way you can also validate your own data.

Comment: @SamSwift웃 what do you mean exactly by script ? Could you elaborate a bit more on your idea ?
@Qirel hmm, wouldn't that bee too complicated and lengthy to do ? Here's a perfect example, where it works just the way I need to
`http://yaez.de/abo`
So it must be possible with just JS..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting a return false you are basically hijacking the functionality of the form - it's not posting to google at all like that. Try submitting the form using `AJAX`. With jQuery it could be done like this:

```
$("#ajaxForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/FORMKEY/formResponse",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'chrome-extension://EXTENSION_ID');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT');
        },
        data: JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        statusCode: {
            0: function () {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Your form has been submitted!";
                window.location.replace("http://thankyoupage.html");
            },
            200: function () {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Your form has been submitted!";
                console.log("Success");
                window.location.replace("ThankYou.html");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you. In this case, do I need to remove the target from the form as well ? So far I've added the ID ajaxForm to my form element and of course removed the action and method.
Changed the url of the function to point to the google sheet and edited the replace url. But it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Is there any js errors? Notice that in the url of my example it needs `FORMKEY` for the particular form in google you are trying to reference. That may be the issue

Comment: yes, I do have a formkey. It just opens up a new tab with a long string of all the form field data. Also here are some jquery errors from the console
http://s23.postimg.org/9tyqmkmwb/Capture.png

Comment: You're using worpdress so change the `$` signs to `jQuery` such as: jQuery('#ajaxForm').submit()

Comment: okey, thanks. Now it does indeed redirect to the desired page, however it doesn't send any data... Did you write the above function yourself, or you got it from somewhere? I'd like to know more about it, as there are a few things I don't understand...